# Script to check permissions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, containers

I'm trying to make a script to check the permissions of a file inside a container in docker, but it keeps me saying "Binary operator expected"

I've tried to add "test" (I've seen it throught internet, but it doesn't worked.)

```
#!/bin/bash
docker exec -i container1 touch /home/ubuntu/tryme

if [ -f -rwx container1:/home/ubuntu/tryme ];
   then
     echo "Full Permissions";
   else
     echo "Not every permission. It will be updated"
    docker exec -i container1 chmod 777 /home/ubuntu/tryme;
   fi
```

That's the part of the script which is giving me headache

I was expecting to work it nicely, but it keeps saying "Binary operator expected"

Comment: Are you sure ```-f -rwx container1:/home/ubuntu/tryme``` returns boolean (true / false) value?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/DDv1EC2.png

Comment: Im quite pissed off... It's something "Easy" but it ain't working.

Comment: can you try using `[[` for `if` condition, like: `if [[ ..... ]];`

Comment: Syntactic error :/

Comment: Make one check a time and join them with `&&`.

Comment: ```if [[ -f myfile.ext && -x myfile.ext ]]; then echo "FileExist and Executable";
 else echo "FileNotExist or Not executable"; fi;```

Comment: `chmod 777` ? 

Comment: Also, do you expect accessing the file inside the container as `container1:/home/ubuntu/tryme` to work directly from outside the container?

Comment: What is `-f -rwx` supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So:

1. Get file permissions.
2. Check if the file permissions is what you desire.

Like:

```
filepermissions=$(stat -c '%a' /home/ubuntu/tryme)
if [ "$filepermissions" = "777" ]; then
    echo "File permissions are set to 777"
else
    echo "They are not set to 777"
fi
```

The `[ -f -rwx container1:/home/ubuntu/tryme ]` is invalid. The `-f` flag from `test` checks (from [man test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test)):

```
-f FILE
    FILE exists and is a regular file
```

The `-f -rwx` check if file `-rwx` exists. Then the third argument is invalid and `[` or `test` expects a `binary operation`. It expects a `-o` or `-a` binary operation as the third argument, any other is invalid and does not make any sense.

If the file is inside docker, it's simple to modify the script, to get the file permissions inside docker container context:

```
filepermissions=$(docker exec -i container1 stat -c '%s' /home/ubuntu/tryme)
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks buddy <3